# Comment system php

Tags: php, comments, review

i have problem with making my comment system.
We have a projekt about book rating/review/comments, but the problem is that we need to make a comment system, where the comments won't be posted until the admin accept the comment by adminpanel.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add one more column into your db table, something like `is_published` and check it.

Answer (score 0):

are u working on core php or anyother framework. Wordpress has default feature as mentioned above. for core php ,You can write a php function to validate , for admin approval , for the comment to be approved.